# TelephonyManager.iccTransmitApduBasicChannel data argument format

Tags: android, modem, apdu, sim-card, secure-element

I am using Telephony Manager to transmit APDU commands to the SIM. I have the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission.

I am using the below function:

```
String iccTransmitApduBasicChannel (int cla, int instruction, int p1, int p2, int p3, String data)
```

I want to know the format of the argument `data`. Is it in int or hex or other format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` parameter of the method `iccTransmitApduBasicChannel()` corresponds to the DATA field of the APDU. Each byte of that field is represented as 2-digit hexadecimal value.

Comment: for example for data 7F FF 6F E3, string will simply be "7FFF6FE3" ??